# React - search input not filtering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed a search input here: **https://codesandbox.io/s/k9448q2v87** that works, but not properly.

The input is able to find files inside the **main folder** **(called ['.'])** and the subfolders **(/bin, /lib, /spec)**, but **doesn't find the files inside those subfolders** and **the main folder**.

For example, if you try to search for **01_greeting_spec.rb** or **greeting.rb**, the search will not filter properly.

But, If you search for a folder like **/bin**, the input filters the folder and all the files inside.

**So, what is missing?**

Consider the annexed Stack Snippet to this question.

```js
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "Select A Node To See Its Data Structure Here..."
    };
    this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
  }

  changeContent(newContent) {
    this.setState({
      content: newContent
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      content: nextProps.content
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        <div className="content_box">{this.state.content}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
  }

  inputChange(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(content);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input className="form-control" placeholder="Search the tree..." onChange={this.inputChange} />
    );
  }
}

let data = [
  {
    type: "directory",
    name: ".",
    contents: [
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./bin",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./bin/greet" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./lib",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./lib/greeting.rb" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./spec",
        contents: [
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/01_greeting_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/02_cli_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/spec_helper.rb" }
        ]
      },
      { type: "file", name: "./CONTRIBUTING.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile.lock" },
      { type: "file", name: "./LICENSE.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./README.md" }
    ]
  }
];

// Icon file image for 'FileTree'
const FileIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="icon-file-text2"
        className="icon"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        fill="currentColor"
        width="1em"
        height="1em"
      >
        <path d="M28.681 7.159c-0.694-0.947-1.662-2.053-2.724-3.116s-2.169-2.030-3.116-2.724c-1.612-1.182-2.393-1.319-2.841-1.319h-15.5c-1.378 0-2.5 1.121-2.5 2.5v27c0 1.378 1.122 2.5 2.5 2.5h23c1.378 0 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5v-19.5c0-0.448-0.137-1.23-1.319-2.841zM24.543 5.457c0.959 0.959 1.712 1.825 2.268 2.543h-4.811v-4.811c0.718 0.556 1.584 1.309 2.543 2.268zM28 29.5c0 0.271-0.229 0.5-0.5 0.5h-23c-0.271 0-0.5-0.229-0.5-0.5v-27c0-0.271 0.229-0.5 0.5-0.5 0 0 15.499-0 15.5 0v7c0 0.552 0.448 1 1 1h7v19.5z" />
        <path d="M23 26h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
        <path d="M23 22h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
        <path d="M23 18h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Icon folder image for 'FileTree'
 const FolderIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="icon-folder"
        className="icon"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        fill="currentColor"
        height="1em"
        width="1em"
      >
        <path d="M14 4l4 4h14v22h-32v-26z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Icon arrow image for 'FileTree'
 const TriangleDown = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="svg__icon--triangle-down"
        viewBox="0 0 9 4.5"
        fill="currentColor"
        height="1em"
        width="1em"
      >
        <path d="M0,0,4.5,4.5,9,0Z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Filters file 'name' and adds '/'
const formatName = name => {
  return name.substr(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
};

// Dummy data set
var root = data[0];

// Construction of FileTree
 class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: null
    };
    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ searchTerm }) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name });
    this.props.liftStateUp(name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        {renderTree(
          this.props.root || root,
          this.setActiveNode,
          this.state.activeNode,
          null,
          this.state.searchTerm
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Directory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: true,
    };
    this.toggleDirectory = this.toggleDirectory.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDirectory() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }

  hasMatchingNodes() {
    const filteredNodes = this.props.node.contents.filter(
      (node) => {
      return (
        node.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) >
        -1
      );
    });

    console.log(this.props.searchTerm);
    return filteredNodes.length > 0;
  }
  render() {
    let node = this.props.node;

    if (this.props.searchTerm && !this.hasMatchingNodes()) return null;
    return (
      <div className="directory-container">
        <div className="directory">
          <div
            className=
            {`directory__toggle ${ this.state.expanded ? "expanded" : ""}`}
          >
            <div onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
              <TriangleDown />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="directory__icon" onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
            <FolderIcon />
          </div>

          <div className="directory__name" onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
            <div>{formatName(node.name)}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.expanded
          ? node.contents.map((content, index) =>
              renderTree(
                content,
                this.props.setActiveNode,
                this.props.activeNode,
                index,
                this.props.searchTerm
              )
            )
          : ""}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Set class Active do selected file
const File = ({ name, setActiveNode, activeNode, searchTerm }) => {
  if (searchTerm && name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) < 0)
    return null;
  let isActive = activeNode === name;
  let className = isActive ? "active" : "";

  return (
    <div className={className + " file"} onClick={() => setActiveNode(name)}>
      <div className="file__icon">
        <FileIcon />
      </div>
      <div className="file__name">{formatName(name)}</div>
      {isActive && <div className="file__options">...</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

var renderTree = (node, setActiveNode, activeNode, index, searchTerm) => {
  if (node.type === "file") {
    return (
      <File
        key={index}
        name={node.name}
        setActiveNode={setActiveNode}
        activeNode={activeNode}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
      />
    );
  } else if (node.type === "directory") {
    return (
      <Directory
        key={index}
        node={node}
        setActiveNode={setActiveNode}
        activeNode={activeNode}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  liftStateUp = (data) => {
    this.setState({ activeNode: data });
  };

  onChange(data) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: data });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <SearchEngine className="form-control" onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FileTree
            liftStateUp={this.liftStateUp}
            searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <TextBox content={this.state.activeNode} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #212830;
  color: #9ea1b2 !important;
}

.directory {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.directory__toggle {
  padding-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.directory__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory__name {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory-container {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
}

.file__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file__name {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file__options {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #31343f;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.svg-icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.expanded {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

/** CONTENT BOX **/

.padd_top {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.content_box {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-color: #282c34;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #9da5ab;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.text_color {
  color: #21252b !important;
}

/** SEARCH **/

.form-control {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

/** ARROW ANIMATION **/

.rotate {
  animation: rotate-keyframes 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate-keyframes {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
 <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
 <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
 <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
 <noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
 </noscript>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Thank you for the help.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"Please check the link above. All the code is there."* No. :-) The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). This often means trimming, see the link. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: (In your case, it may not be possible to make it runnable on-site, if this is React native or similar.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the advice. I was trying to make the question not so long because of the massive code I have at the moment, and also a way for people to see the code working.
Thanks again!

Comment: The [mcve] article contains a link to a blog post called "how to debug small programs". It's good advice. Isolating the minimal code that can reproduce the bug gets you 90% towards solving most bugs. And people who might want to help you out here on stackoverflow are **much** more likely to submit an answer if they don't have to spend 20 minutes going through your code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hasMatchingNodes` method does not check child directories recursively. It only checks the names of files and folders that are direct children of the root directory `.`

You should test the names of file nodes, and call the matching function recursively if the node is a directory, and compare the search term with the node name if the node is a file.

```
hasMatchingNodes() {
  const searchTerm = this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  const matchNode = node =>
    node.contents
      ? node.contents.some(matchNode)
      : node.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
  return matchNode(this.props.node);
}
```

See updated app here: https://codesandbox.io/s/245nv8n3j